How to use pivot_longer to combine multiple columns in R with dplyr
I'm working with a data set that looks something like this. I'm trying to use pivot_longer and dplyr to get the means and sd under their own respective columns so I can do some plotting but I can't seem to get it to work properly. Could someone give me some tips?



day
mean_depth
depth_sd
mean_temp
temp_sd




2021-01-01
20.5
5.2
15.8
3.8


2021-01-02
15.5
3.9
15.6
2.2



I hope to end up with a table that looks like this:



day
variable
mean
sd




2021-01-01
depth
20.5
5.2


2021-01-01
temp
15.8
3.8


2021-01-02
depth
15.5
3.9


2021-01-02
temp
15.6
2.2




What code have you tried?

If you clean up the column names so the variable is awlays first or always last, this is easier. For example
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dd %>% 
  rename_with(.cols=starts_with("mean"), function(x) gsub("([^_]*)_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", x)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-day, names_pattern="(.*)_(.*)", names_to=c("variable", ".value"))

This returns
  day        variable  mean    sd
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 depth     20.5   5.2
2 2021-01-01 temp      15.8   3.8
3 2021-01-02 depth     15.5   3.9
4 2021-01-02 temp      15.6   2.2

Tested with
dd <- read.table(text="day  mean_depth  depth_sd    mean_temp   temp_sd
2021-01-01  20.5    5.2 15.8    3.8
2021-01-02  15.5    3.9 15.6    2.2", header=T)


When I run that code separately (using the df created after running the df %% rename_with(.cols=starts_with("mean"), function(x) gsub("([^]*)(.)", "\2_\1", x)) and then run df %>% pivot_longer(-day, names_pattern="(.)_(.*)", names_to=c("variable", ".value")) I don't get the same solution. I get NA values and depth, sd, and temp become their own columns. Could you please clarify why that is and post the solution using pivot_longer, when the names are always last or first, say like it was like that to begin with?

Did you save the results from the rename somewhere? Rename doesn't change the data frame itself, it returns a new data.frame with updated valves. You want the value that's going to go in the "variable" column to always be before the _ or after it so you can more easily place the values into the appropriate columns. If there is order it's easier to automate.

@fishlakeslimno you left out the pipe %>% before pivot_longer(...) then

Yes I did save it into a new dataframe and tried to run the pivot_longer separately. Apologies, perhaps I'm not clear. I'm wondering why, after saving the new dataframe created using rename, the code creates NAs. This is what I'm running: dd <- read.table(text="day  mean_depth  depth_sd    mean_temp   temp_sd
2021-01-01  20.5    5.2 15.8    3.8
2021-01-02  15.5    3.9 15.6    2.2", header=T)
dd1 <- dd %>% pivot_longer(-day, names_pattern="(.)_(.)", names_to=c("variable", ".value")) ,,, I want to know how to run pivot_longer as if the dataframe created using rename was the original df

You didn't do any renaming in what you just showed. If the column names where "day depth_mean depth_sd temp_mean temp_sd" then this would work fine. But you still have them as "day mean_depth depth_sd mean_temp temp_sd"

I see sorry!, been a long week. Thank you so much!

Well if you do understand regex, you could use:
dd %>%
pivot_longer(-day, names_to = c('.value', 'variable'), 
                 names_pattern = "(?|(mean)_(.+)|(?:(?=.*(sd))(.+)_))")

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  day        variable  mean    sd
  <chr>      <chr>    <dbl> <dbl>
1 2021-01-01 depth     20.5   5.2
2 2021-01-01 temp      15.8   3.8
3 2021-01-02 depth     15.5   3.9
4 2021-01-02 temp      15.6   2.2

There are other regex patterns that could still be used.

Here is an example using the built-in iris dataset:
First, we grab observations comparable to your data and rename the columns so that the name and value are separated by an underscore.
sample <- iris[50:51,]
colnames(sample)[1:4] <- c("Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width",
                    "Petal_Length", "Petal_Width")

According to documentation for pivot_longer(), ".value" can be used to work with multiple values. It replaces passing an argument to values_to. Voila.
sample %>%
      pivot_longer(cols = c("Sepal_Length", "Sepal_Width",
                     "Petal_Length", "Petal_Width"), # choose name-value pairs to pivot. 
      names_to = c("Part_of_flower", ".value"),
      names_sep = "_") 

